# To harbour as a verb

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice, phrases

I am currently writing a paper and am kind of struggling with the *corrections* my co-writer did on my sections (he is the main author and I only had to write a few chapters).

There is a phrase in here that is odd to me, please tell me if that is something you can, at least in principle do:

"Tow-dimensional histograms harboured two main clusters ...".

Can you use harbour in this context ?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. One of the expectations of Stack Exchange is that you demonstrate your initial efforts at research, such as checking a dictionary for definitions with which you may not be familiar. This use of *harboured* seems reasonable to me. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: What did it say before? What *is* the context?

Comment: @choster Well I did of course search for this but could not find any example in which harbour was used as a verb together with inanimate objects. That is what initially made me wonder, besides the fact that this just sounds strange to me.

Comment: @JasonBassford Regarding the context: The sentence is supposed to say something about clusters in a plot. Meaning if you look at this referenced illustration there will be two prominent "spots", catching your eye. I hope this description helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb to harbor (using the American spelling):

> transitive verb.

1a : to give shelter or refuge to harboring a fugitive.

b : to be the home or habitat of

The ledges still harbor rattlesnakes. broadly : contain

a town that harbors several textile factories.

2 : to hold especially persistently in the mind : cherish harbored a grudge.

| Definition of Harbor by Merriam-Webster

[definition here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harbor)

The general definition, contain (as a town might contain factories) covers the sense in which the author has used it.

Comment: "a town that harbors several textile factories."

Okay, thanks.

Answer (score -3):

No, you can't; the apparent metaphorical connotations of this verb include specifically the idea that what is contained has the ability to develop. The OALD gives for instance the following  definition and example.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/harbour_2)
>   ) **3** to contain something and allow it to develop.
>
> - Your dishcloth can harbour  many germs.

Basically, you can say that the histogram **shows** two main clusters.

Comment: The idea that something may develop is only one possible metaphorical use of this verb, and not the most common.

Comment: @Xanne Well, my answer is not fundamentally wrong: you find in the SOED "Now freq. give secret refuge to (a wanted criminal, a noxious animal, etc.)

Comment: Your answer of *no, you can't* ***is*** fundamentally wrong. You're taking one specific sense of the word and turning it into a prohibitive generalization.

Comment: @JasonBassford Can you give refuge (secret) to a sentence? Highly poetical, for the least!